# Wordpress import does not fetch images, but just links them

Tags: plugins, import, xml

I have used the [**Wordpress Importer plugin**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/) to export content from site 1 and import into site 2.

When exporting content, i selected "All content" and downloaded the export XML file.

Then when i imported the XML file into site 2, i selected "Download & Import File attachments". Though i got a bunch of errors at the end of the process saying that "Failed to import media", i see that all posts and pages have got the corresponding images in them.

But what i saw is that, the image is referring to the first site.
I am not sure whether this is the default behavior of Wordpress Importer.

Is there a good plugin that can fetch all images from site 1 to site 2, while importing content?

Otherwise, what i am planning to do is to copy all media images (**wp-content/uploads** folder) from site 1 to site 2, and then before importing XML file of site 1 into site 2, change the media links of XML file, to point to site 2.
It is suggested in a [**forum page**](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/import-feature-does-not-import-file-attachments#post-1926884).

But i see that this approach is an odd one. Can someone suggest me a better way to tackle this?

Comment: I'd guess you need to copy the wp-content/uploads directory across too?

Comment: @Rup That is what i am referring to in my question, if there is no plugin that can efficiently import media content. I have to copy the entire "uploads" directory content from site 1 to site 2.

Comment: Are those sites hosted on the same server?

Comment: No, they are hosted on different servers.

Answer (score 2):

If the url changed for your new site you'll have to do a search and replace of the old urls in your database. Always make a backup first.

See this Codex reference to do this safely:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#When_Your_Domain_Name_or_URLs_Change

Comment: Yes, he says he's planning to do that in the XML export.